# Send mail via SendGrid to Outlook was always failing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am a newbie in using SendGrid. I have a web application that send a mail to users after the successful registration. I am using send grid to send mails.

It works fine when I try to send Google email accounts. But when I send mails to Outlook email addresses, it always failed to deliver emails.

I checked the SendGrid 'Activity' section it shows like below.

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem. I have configured the domain and the problem still persists. I contacted sendgrid support and they tell me that it is because we use shared IPs and because of some users we are blacklisted.

Comment: When I tried from Postman it is not receiving emails but from mobile app it is working, don't know the reason :)

Answer (score 3):

You might need to setup domain authentication. This link should be a good place to start:  https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/

Outlook might have different firewall rules blocking incoming (potentially malicious) emails while GMail might have a different set of them.

Comment: i did that, its not solving anything.